# htaccess - Allow viewing of index.html via www.example.com/foo instead of www.example.com/foo/index.html

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-authz-host

So I have a hypothetical folder on my website protected by `Deny from all` on my `.htaccess` file. I have coded an exception as below:

```
<files index.html>
order allow,deny
Allow from all
</files>
```

If a user types `www.example.com/path/index.html` they are able to see the webpage just fine. However, if they go by the more "user-friendly" approach and type `www.example.com/path` they are given a `403 Forbidden` error. Since both paths are accessing the same file, I fail to see how one would work and another would not. There are no other index files in the directory that could potentially be interfering with `index.html`. Is there a way to configure `.htaccess` in a way that allows this second path? Any solution is acceptable, including ones outside the realm of `.htaccess`; yes I have PHP, no I do not have AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify just the bare directory mod_dir issues an internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex (which I assume is configured to serve `index.html` in your case). "The problem" is that the `<Files>` directive is first processed *before* the subrequest occurs. But before this subrequest occurs the filename that the `<Files>` directive matches against has not yet been resolved; it is empty! So, we need to match against an *empty* filename.

However, once the subrequest for `index.html` (the DirectoryIndex) has occurred then the `<Files>` container is reprocessed (in a `.htaccess` context), but this time the filename has resolved to `index.html`. So, we need to match against `index.html` as well!

This can be accounted for by either having two `<Files>` containers. For example:

```
<Files "">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>

<Files "index.html">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Or (preferably) combining these into a single `<FilesMatch>` container (that accepts a regex as the argument). For example:

```
<FilesMatch ^(index\.html)?$>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

By making the filename *optional* (trailing `?`) this effectively matches both passes: an empty filename and `index.html`.

Note that if both the URLs `/` *and* `/index.html` are available and serve the same content then you should canonicalise the URL in some way to avoid potential duplicate content issues. (Preferably a redirect from `/index.html` to `/`.)

---

> ...and type `www.example.com/path`

Just to clarify, if the user *types* `www.example.com/path`, where `path` is a filesystem directory and a trailing slash is omitted from the URL, then mod_dir will (by default) issue an external 301 redirect to `www.example.com/path/` (with a trailing slash) in order to "fix" the URL. So the URL we are dealing with is really `www.example.com/path/`.

Answer (score 0):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

"The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for, when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a / at the end of the directory name..."

```
# Example A: Set index.html as an index page, then add index.php to that list as well.
<Directory "/foo">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>

# Example B: This is identical to example A, except it's done with a single directive.
<Directory "/foo">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>

# Example C: To replace the list, you must explicitly reset it first:
# In this example, only index.php will remain as an index resource.
<Directory "/foo">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>`
```

Comment: This still doesn't change the fact that the directory is denied from all by default, and the user cannot access index.html in the first place. I sincerely appreciate the help, but you might have to read the question a little more closely.

Comment: @hjk321 This answer is not an unreasonable suggestion. If the `DirectoryIndex` was not set, or set incorrectly, then you would also get a 403 Forbidden response - which is exactly what you are seeing. However, even if the `DirectoryIndex` is correctly set (which it probably is, unless you have explicitly overridden this), the single `<Files>` container in your question will still result in a 403 Forbidden. See my answer for how to fix this.